'KroneckerDelta' won't evaluate symbolically
I'm trying to get Mathematica to symbolically evaluate sums containing KroneckerDelta.
It picks out the correct term when comparing the index agains a number, but not when comparing against a variable.
This works:
In[1]:= Sum[KroneckerDelta[j, 2] * f[j], {j, 1, 3}]

Out[1]= f[2]

This doesn't work (should evaluate to f[a]):
In[2]:= $Assumptions =  a \[Element] {1, 2, 3}

Out[2]= a \[Element] {1, 2, 3}


In[3]:= Sum[KroneckerDelta[j, a] * f[j], {j, 1, 3}]  // FullSimplify

Out[3]= f[1] KroneckerDelta[1, a] + f[2] KroneckerDelta[2, a] + 
 f[3] KroneckerDelta[3, a]


This question has been asked before, but the answers I found say

that it only worked in Mathmatica 8,
or to simplify it using PiecewiseExpand (which outputs the same terms in piecewise notation, but also doesn't simplify them to a single term, at least in Mathematica 12.1),
or to use DiscreteDelta instead (which does the same as PiecewiseExpand).


Is there some trick to get it working, or is KroneckerDelta just broken?

Why do you think it should evaluate to f[a]? So if a=7 then according to you the result should be f[7] but correct result is 0 because the sum is only for indices 1 to 3.

If anything's broken here, it's FullSimplify, not KroneckerDelta. In a new kernel, try Reap[FullSimplify[Sum[KroneckerDelta[j, a]*f[j], {j, 1, 3}], a == 1 || a == 2 || a == 3, ComplexityFunction -> (LeafCount[Sow[#]] &)]][[2]] to verify that FullSimplify doesn't consider f[a] as a hypothesis. (You can't do this in an existing kernel because FullSimplify caches a bunch of state.)

@azerbajdzan Because of $Assumptions =  a \[Element] {1, 2, 3}. Should't FullSimplify take that into account?

@Fii Well, yes it should, from the point of view of human, but Mathematica is not always that clever. And the second point is that its output is still correct although maybe not the simplest one.

@PatrickStevens I'm not sure if I'm interpreting the output correctly, but f[a] does definitely not show up in the list of expressions.

@azerbajdzan Yeah, that seems to be very common with Mathematica and FullSimplify :/ It does have all the required information and assumptions tho, and f[a] should be considered the simpler output by pretty much any measure, so it must be that FullSimplify is just not applying the right transformations...
